# Is there any ecu(engine control unit)in a 70 cc bike like Honda cd 70?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, electronic-control-module, small-engine

I know that ecu is there in cars but I am confused is there any ecu(engine control unit) in a 70 cc bike like Honda cd 70?

Answer (score 0):

There are small engines with an ECU (e.g. the Honda Monkey with a 125ccm motor), but the Honda CD 70 does not have an ECU (the closest it has is an [electronic ignition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_discharge_ignition)).

Engine size is not the deciding difference here. But ECU usually means "fuel injection", and the CD 70 is a carbureted bike.

The ECU takes sensor readings for the throttle position and the exhaust (and maybe others) and from that computes the optimal mix of gasoline and air (actually Honda uses fuel maps that contains fuel/air rations based on empirical data and the sensors are for corrections based on environmental factors). That's good for fuel efficiency and environmental standards (I live in the European Union and here bikes with carburetors practically died out after the introduction of the Euro 3 norm - apparently getting a carbureted bike to meet emission standards is not that easy). But this takes a lot of parts and expensive electronics, and if you design a mass market bike for an area with less strict emission standards you will probably opt for the cheaper solution.